# DateTime() works wrong

Tags: php, date, symfony, time

There is situation in PHP Symfony2:

```
$myDate = new \DateTime();
var_dump($myDate);
```

Returns:

```
class DateTime#17476 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2014-05-26 14:44:53"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Warsaw"
}
```

But:

```
$myDate = new \DateTime();
var_dump($myDate->date);
```

Returns... `NULL`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly because you're using it wrong, you need to properly use DateTime methods.

In this case, use **`->format()`**. For more information please read the [**manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Consider this example:

```
$myDate = new \DateTime();
// yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
echo $myDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output: 2014-05-26 20:54:21
// timestamp
echo $myDate->getTimestamp(); // output: 1401108861
```